# Mongoid- accepts_nested_attributes_for not saving 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-many

I have a one to many relationship between `EnquiryForm` and `UniversityFeeInstallment` EnquiryForm `has_many` UniversityFeeInstallment.
Following is the `params` I receive from contoller

```
{
"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"jqgiRlk606pDzMEAtS/mGoWz8T61PgyCkKdMzSHEiQA=",
"enquiry"=>{
    "university_fee_installments_attributes"=>{
        "1338318502006"=>{
            "due_date"=>"2012-05-28",
            "amount"=>"1200"
        }
    }
},
"commit"=>"Update Enquiry",
"id"=>"4fc3db492d6d130238000028"
```

}

I am using Ryan Bates classic nested form technique. 
Also model code is :

```
 has_many :development_fee_installments, :autosave => true 
  has_many :university_fee_installments, :autosave => true 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :development_fee_installments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :university_fee_installments
```

Controller:

```
def update
  @enquiry = Enauiry.find(params[:id])
  if @enquiry.save
    redirect_to enquiry_payments_path(@enquiry, :notice => "Installment details updated")
  else
    render 'edit_installments'
  end
end
```

I am not able to save university_fee_installments.

Comment: please give your code of controller so that we can figure out how you are going with the params

Comment: @Cage : updated controller code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller code to this

```
def update
    @enquiry = Enquiry.find(params[:id])
    if @enquiry.update_attributes(params[:enquiry])
        redirect_to enquiry_payments_path(@enquiry, :notice => "Installment details updated")
    else
        render 'edit_installments'
    end
end
```

update_attributes will do the trick as we are passing the params we received from view in that.

Comment: Ohh my god...How can I miss that.. I guess I am tired and need a holiday.. :)